# multiple sql join in laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

hi im fairly new in laravel 4.2 so i have this table (table 1) which gets data from a related table (table 2) but table 2 also gets from another related table (table 3) here is a visualization 
[image]

im using laravel 4.2 query builder for this here is my sample code on how im connecting table 1 and table 2

```
$records = DB::table('table1')
            ->join('table2', 'table1.someID', '=', 'table2.someID')
            ->select('select something')
            ->get();
```

my problem is i don't know how to get the values from table 3 is there a way for this?
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe add another join for table 3? ->join('table3', 'table3.someID', '=', 'table2.someID')

Comment: will try that out. thanks!

Comment: that did the trick! thanks :) can you put your answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm.. I don't really mind but, here you go. You just have to put another join to get the values to the third table from the table 2 judging from the visual above.

```
$records = DB::table('table1')
            ->join('table2', 'table1.someID', '=', 'table2.someID')
            ->join('table3', 'table3.someID', '=', 'table2.someID')
            ->select('select something')
            ->get();
```

Comment: No problem, never thought I would be much help. Glad I helped you. :)